# Why doesn't my Macbook see my phone (droid incredible, cyanogen)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb, connection-issues, macos

I an Android newbie and software developer.  I just got this used HTC Droid Incredible and installed cyanogen on it.  I read that when I plug it in to the laptop with a USB cable I should see a notification at the top of the phone's screen, and then be able to copy over music, etc.  But I plug it in and nothing happens.  What's wrong?  What can I do?  The first thing I wanted to do was load some music.

Comment: Try a different USB port, try rebooting the phone, try a different cable.

Comment: Tried 2 of 3.  I'll report back when I've found a different cable.

Comment: That was it.  The non-working cable was a brand new cable from the store, but it was part of a boost mobile car charger.  It works for charging.  Are some USB cables power only, and not data?

Comment: Not that I know of, some are just shoddy :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the cable.  The store gave me a new cable, but it was power only.  I didn't know some cables were power, but no data.   I'll be returning that.   Thanks to Matthew for his suggestion in the comment.